# Twitter4j Stream not Closing?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I have been searching all over the internet for a way to stop the stream of tweets from Twitter's Streaming API. I saw this bit of code, but nothing happens when it is exicuted, and i still get tweets. I have also tried to set the connection to null, which gave me an error:

```
Stream.shutdown();
```

How can i stop this stream? Thanks.

Here is some more of my code:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxxxxx").setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxxxx").setOAuthAccessToken("xxxxxx").setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxxxx");
TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
```

After this, i check a boolean to see wheather i should close the stream or note. If flase, then i do. (sort of swapped around, but false = close here). Here is that it is eclosed in:

```
if(!CheckTweets)
{
    Stream.shutdown();
}
else
{
    // Show Tweets....
}
```

Comment: You could try `Stream.cleanUp()` before calling `Stream.shutdown()`. But shutdown should do the job all by itself...

Comment: @WilliamGaul I have tried that, but nothing happens. Let me try it again, maybe i missed something. Do you need some more of my code?

Comment: Yeah, post up the part around where you call shutdown(). Such as the enclosing method.

Comment: @WilliamGaul i edited the Question, and added some detail.

Comment: @WilliamGaul i tried what you said earlier, but it did not work.

Comment: Hmm are you sure the shutdown even gets called? So if you add a print statement right before `shutdown()` in the if-block, will it get printed?

Comment: @WilliamGaul I actually did that, and it was being called. Also, lets continue this in chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38517/discussion-between-elite-gamer-and-william-gaul)

Comment: @EliteGamer Did you manage to get this sorted out?

Comment: @Jonathan no i did not

Comment: @EliteGamer Ok. You should add more code to your question, it's not clear where the problem could be from what you've posted.